# $all parameter in mongodb does not work with ObjectId list

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, object-identity

I retrieve a list of ObjectId and I want to retrieve all object in my mongo database using the parameter $all

I'm using pymongo and my request look like this :

```
db.database.collection.find({ "_id" : { "$all" : [ObjectId('4ee371837c93dd33dc000003'),ObjectId('4eef9f647c93dd1a90000000')] } })
```

but the cursor count returned by the request is 0
but when I do this request:

```
db.database.collection.find_one({ "_id" : ObjectId('4ee371837c93dd33dc000003')})
```

It returns me the good object

Anyone know why it does not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That query does not make sense. You are asking for the unique and single-valued `_id` field to have *all* of two distinct values *at the same time*.

I think you want `$in`:

```
db.database.collection.find({ "_id" : { 
   "$in" : 
     [ObjectId('4ee371837c93dd33dc000003'),
      ObjectId('4eef9f647c93dd1a90000000')] } })
```